# search for multiline substring in a string

Tags: delphi

my code is below

```
procedure TfrmMain.btncheckclick(Sender: TObject);
var
target: Ansistring;
htmlCode: string;
begin
target := ('<span class="underline">' +
'                                      <h2>');
htmlCode:= GetWebBrowserHTML();

if    (Pos(target, htmlCode) > 0)
then
begin
showmessage ('yes');
end;
exit;

end;
```

When the user presses button, it should check the string for the substring and if it exists it should show message, but i could not get the code to work. Help is highly appreciated!

The substring I am searching for is a Multiline substring , "target". I have never been able to get the message to show up even though i know that it exists in the string. Thank you for your helps

Comment: Your `target` string is NOT multi-line. It has no line break in it. You put a line break as whitespace in the code, that DOES NOT put a line break in the `target` string content. You have to code in the line break explicitly, eg: `target := '<span class="underline">' + #13#10 + '                                      <h2>';` You are better off using a substring search that does not rely on line breaks at all.

Comment: Wrong solution. Use an html parser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your correct solution Remy Leabeau. I did exactly what you said and problem sorted!

Ultimately as for David Heffernan's comment, it is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: Remy, which substring search would you recommend that does not rely on line breaks?

Comment: @WhizLady201777: David's comment is not misleading, it is correct. You got an answer that does what you asked, but note that, generally, to solve similar problems with HTML, you need an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
target := ('<span class="underline">' +
'                                      <h2>');
```

the `target` variable does not contain what you think, it's `<span class="underline">         <h2>`.

So, you need to pass the value as below:

```
target := '<span class="underline">' + #13#10 + ' "how many spaces here?" <h2>';
```

For example:

```
var Str , Sub : String;
begin
    Str := 'Stack '+#13#10+'      Overflow';
    Sub := 'k '+ #13#10+'      Overflow';
    if pos (Sub , Str) > 0 then
        Showmessage (Sub+' found!')
            else
                Showmessage(Sub+' not found!');
end;
```

Output:

k

Overflow found!

Comment: Also thank you very much for your correct solution also. One other method I tried was

         target := '<span class="underline">' +chr(13) + ' <h2>';
hoping the chr(13) would add a return and it would act as a new line, but that never worked.

#13#10 was the way forward. Thank you